# Svelte : data-binding for an accordion picker

Tags: typescript, components, accordion, svelte

I 'm playing around Svelte (JS) to produce an medical survey purpose app. 
My data is about { categories, tests, subtests}

I need to use a accordion subtests picker to feed *résumé* entries.

A design choice is to merge categories and tests levels, due to volumetry.
User picks a category + test and accordion reveals subtests one can choose..

I'm not so familiar with two-way data bindings with Svelte.
I had tried this, but results in a type error : 'ctx.selected ' is not efined.

```
<section>
  <h1>Pick subtests you need in accordion list</h1>

  <div class="accordion">
    {#each cats_tests as ct, ctidx }
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h2 class="ct-heading">
         <label>
           <input bind:group='selected' value={ ctidx }  type=checkbox />
           <span>{ ctidx }: { ct.name }</span>
         </label>
        </h2>
        {#if selected[ctidx] }
          {#each ct.subtests as sub, subidx }
            <div transition:fade>
              <h3 class="subtest-heading">
                <label for="ct-{ctidx}-sub-{subidx}">
                  <input  id="ct-{ctidx}-sub-{subidx}" type="checkbox" />
                  <span>{ subidx }: { sub.name }</span>
                </label>
              </h3>
            </div>
          {/each}
       {/if}
      </div>
    {/each}
  </div>
</section>

<script>
  import { fade } from 'svelte-transitions'

  export default {
    transitions: { fade},

    oncreate() {

    },

    data() {
      return {
        cats_tests: [
          {
            name: 'Cat A - Test 1',
            subtests: [
              { name: 'subtest-s'},
              { name: 'subtest-t'},
              { name: 'subtest-u'}
            ]
          }, {
            name: 'Cat A - Test 2',
              subtests: [
          { name: 'subtest-v'},
          { name: 'subtest-w'},
          { name: 'subtest-x'} ,
          { name: 'subtest-y'}
        ]
          }, {
            name: 'Cat B - Test 3',
            subtests: [
              { name: 'subtest-z'}
            ]
         }
       ]
     }
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
  h2.ct-heading {
    background-color: #d1e1f1;
  }

  h3.subtest-heading {
    padding-left: 15%;
  }

</style>
```

Questions :

1. How to fix that ?
2. How to retrieve picked subtests in other parts of the app, without querying the server ? Consider I'm using the svelte-routing plugin and the store

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 2):

Basically:

one error (missing) add `selected: []`  in data section, of course...

and detecting whioch heading is selected :

```
{#if selected.indexOf(ctidx) > -1 }
  {#each ct.subtests as sub, subidx }
    <div transition:fade>
      // ...
    </div>
   {/each}
 {/if}
```

And that worked for me !